# Jquery: show dialog when loading PDF (e.g. by using jquery.fileDownload.js)

Tags: php, jquery

On my website I have a php-file that's using mpdf-plugin to create a pdf file by doing a query on a MYSQL-database.

The basic url: pdf_report.php?VARa=b&VARb=c. 
(VARa and VARb are used as GET-variables to do query on the database.)

No my real question: I would like to show a loading-dialog that is displayed while the PDF is being produced. When finished the loading-dialog should disappear and the PDF-file downloaded (or displayed in the browser). 
To achieve this I thought I could use the "jquery.fileDownload"-file by using the [examples](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com). But since I'm a very beginner on Jquery I could not find the way to get it to work.

What I've come up so far is (exactly following the examples):

```
<?php 
header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true');
header("Content-type: text/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report_b_c.pdf"');
//b and c are the values of the variables VARa and VARb
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PDF Wait dialog</title>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileDownload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
enter code here
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function () {
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadCustomRichExperience", function () {

    var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");

    $preparingFileModal.dialog({ modal: true });

    $.fileDownload($(this).attr('href'), {
        successCallback: function (url) {

            $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
        },
        failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

            $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
            $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true });
        }
    });
    return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
});
});
</script>
<div id="preparing-file-modal" title="Preparing report..." style="display: none;">
We are preparing your report, please wait...

<div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="width: 100%; height:22px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
</div>

<div id="error-modal" title="Error" style="display: none;">
There was a problem generating your report, please try again.
</div>
<a class="fileDownloadCustomRichExperience" href="pdf_logboek_report.php?VARa=b&VARb=c">Report.pdf</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[edit] 
When running this php-file no errors are shown. Sometimes for 0.5 seconds a dialog is visible and a pdf-file is downloaded. Name of the file: logboek_report_.pdf (this is not the expected file and has empty contents!)

When I run pdf_logboek_report.php?VARa=b&VARb=c the expected pdf-file is created and shown (or downloaded depending on the browser-support).

[edit]
The pdf I want to load would normally take up to 30-60 seconds to be produced.

But unfortunately is does not work as expected because I'm (as a beginner) doing something wrong. OR is the a much simpler way to achieve the dialog the way I would like to have it?!

Please help me out!

Comment: Have you included all the js files ?

Comment: Put alert on `failCallback` and `successCallback`

Comment: Be acquainted with `console.log`/`console.debug`, screw `alert`

Comment: @Alexander... and the horse it rode in on. `!!!` Why not just put the PDF URL in an embedded `iframe`?